# Pass view to struct in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to pass a view into a struct for creating a tab which is the following code:

```
struct TabItem: TabView {
    var tabView: View
    var tabText: String
    var tabIcon: String
    
    var body: some View {
        self.tabView.tabItem {
            Text(self.tabText)
            Image(systemName: self.tabIcon)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                TabItem(tabView: SimpleCalculatorView(), tabText: "Home", tabIcon: "house")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

> Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says here is that the `View` protocol has `associatedtype Body` inside it and thus you can't use the `View` as a type. This means we have to provide more information about the expected type of the `tabView`. One of the solutions would be to use `AnyView` as a type, but that would require additional content wrapping into `AnyView`.

What I would suggest doing here instead of using `AnyView` is to let the compiler figure out the actual `tabView` type for you.

1. Let's tell the compiler that we expect some type `Content` that confirms to the `View` protocol
2. Additionally I don't really see the necessity of using `TabView` as part of the `TabItem` declaration. Try going with just `View` unless you have a strong reason for not doing so.

```swift
struct TabItem<Content: View>: View {   // Content is a type that we expect. `View` is used instead of `TabView` as it is in original code
    var tabView: Content                // Using Content instead of a View as it is an actual type now
    ...
}
```

The rest of the code can stay unmodified.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I've decided a better method is to just use a custom modifier on a View within the TabView since this leaves it as a basic view.